# rails database.yml not accepting ERB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, environment-variables, yaml, erb

In my database.yml, I have:

```
staging:
  adapter: <%= ENV['DATABASE_ADAPTER'] %>
  encoding: <%= ENV['DATABASE_ENCODING'] %>
  database: <%= ENV['DATABASE'] %>
  host: <%= ENV['DATABASE_HOST'] %>
  port: <%= ENV['DATABASE_PORT'].to_i %>
  pool: <%= ENV['DATABASE_POOL'].to_i %>
  username: <%= ENV['DATABASE_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

However, it does not read the ERB part when actually booting puma:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in 
`require': Could not load 'active_record/connection_adapters/<%= ENV['DATABASE_ADAPTER'] %>_adapter'. 
Make sure that the adapter in config/database.yml is valid. If you use an adapter other than 'mysql', 'mysql2', 'postgresql' or 'sqlite3'
add the necessary adapter gem to the Gemfile. (LoadError)
```

which makes no sense, since in the Rails code to load the database configuration:

```
  def database_configuration
    yaml = Pathname.new(paths["config/database"].existent.first || "")

    config = if yaml.exist?
      require "yaml"
      require "erb"
      YAML.load(ERB.new(yaml.read).result) || {}
    elsif ENV['DATABASE_URL']
      # Value from ENV['DATABASE_URL'] is set to default database connection
      # by Active Record.
      {}
    else
      raise "Could not load database configuration. No such file - #{yaml}"
    end

    config
  rescue Psych::SyntaxError => e
    raise "YAML syntax error occurred while parsing #{paths["config/database"].first}. " \
          "Please note that YAML must be consistently indented using spaces. Tabs are not allowed. " \
          "Error: #{e.message}"
  rescue => e
    raise e, "Cannot load `Rails.application.database_configuration`:\n#{e.message}", e.backtrace
  end
```

(taken from the Rails 4.2 stable code, I'm running 4.2.1)

I'm absolutely baffled why this isn't working, any ideas?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I just experienced the same thing, and came across your post.  I had been following a tutorial that had me create a puma.conf file that contained the code below:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection( YAML.load_file( "#{app_dir}/config/database.yml" )[rails_env])
```

I modified to the following, and everything worked as expected:

```
require 'erb'
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection( YAML.load( ERB.new( File.read( "#{app_dir}/config/database.yml" )).result)[rails_env])
```

Comment: I was using an older version (2.11.3), had the issue. Upgraded puma, no change.

Comment: Chris, I edited my answer, don't know if you were notified of the edit, hopefully you'll be notified of this comment and the new answer will solve your issue.

Comment: So what are we supposed to do if we don't want to use puma, for instance, passenger instead?