# Docker + Rails + MySQL = Ignoring environment variables in database.yml

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm newbie using docker and my issue is to load a Rails 4 application using MySQL and Docker with environment variables.

Basically, I build the app and run it. In another terminal I create mysql database and user/password to be used by the database.yml. Here are the steps that I run:

```
$ docker-compose build
$ docker-compose up -d
$ docker exec -it poseidon_db_1 bash -l
#root@dockerimg mysql -uroot -proot
mysql> create database poseidon_development;
mysql> CREATE USER 'poseidon_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'poseidon_password';
mysql> CREATE USER 'poseidon_user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'poseidon_password';
mysql> GRANT ALL ON poseidon_development.* TO 'poseidon_user'@'localhost';
mysql> GRANT ALL ON poseidon_development.* TO 'poseidon_user'@'%';
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
mysql> exit
#root@dockerimg exit
$ docker-compose run web bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

database.yml

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  username: <%= ENV["DATABASE_USERNAME"] %>
  password: <%= ENV["DATABASE_PASSWORD"] %>
  database: <%= ENV["DATABASE_NAME"] %>
  host: db

development:
  <<: *default

test:
  <<: *default
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.6'

services:
  db:
    restart: always
    image: mysql:5.6.34
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - dbdata
    env_file:
      - .env

  dbdata:
    image: tianon/true
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/mysql

  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    volumes:
      - webdata
    links:
      - "db"
    env_file:
      - .env

  webdata:
    image: tianon/true
    volumes:
      - ".:/var/www/poseidon"
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:2.3.7

ENV LANG C.UTF-8

RUN apt-get update -qq
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential mysql-client vim

WORKDIR /tmp
ADD Gemfile Gemfile
ADD Gemfile.lock Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install

ENV APP_ROOT /var/www/poseidon

RUN mkdir -p $APP_ROOT
WORKDIR $APP_ROOT
COPY . $APP_ROOT
RUN chmod a+x .env

EXPOSE 3000

ENTRYPOINT ["bundle", "exec"]

CMD ["rails", "server", "-p", "3000", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

.env

```
SECRET_KEY_BASE=xxxxxxxx
RAILS_ENV=development
RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES=true
URL_OPTIONS=domain.com
RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY=xxxxxxx
RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY=xxxxxxx
MAILGUN_API=xxxxxx
MAILGUN_DOMAIN=xxxxxxx
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
DATABASE_USERNAME=poseidon_user
DATABASE_PASSWORD=poseidon_password
DATABASE_NAME=poseidon_development
```

The problem is, when accessing `http://127.0.0.1`, I receive `Access denied for user '<%= ENV["DATABASE_USERNAME"] %>'@'IP' (using password: YES)`

I don't know what to do anymore, it seems to not load the env vars correctly.

Any help will be really appreciated!

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I was stumped on this issue for a day or two. Things were working fine out of Docker but for some reason within the container the ERB wasn't being parsed.

This post seemed to help: [rails database.yml not accepting ERB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35786885/rails-database-yml-not-accepting-erb) (which I found via [Rails not replace ENV's value in database.yml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47722386/rails-not-replace-envs-value-in-database-yml/47886313#47886313))

> I just experienced the same thing, and came across your post. I had
>   been following a tutorial that had me create a puma.conf file that
>   contained the code below:
>
> ```
> ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection( YAML.load_file( "#{app_dir}/config/database.yml" )[rails_env])
> ```
>
> I modified to the following, and everything worked as expected:
>
> ```
> require 'erb'
> ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection( YAML.load( ERB.new( File.read( "#{app_dir}/config/database.yml" )).result)[rails_env])
> ```