# Why do I get this error "bad URI(is not URI?)" in puma.stderr.log on my ec2 machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puma

When start puma on my ec2 machine, I get this error: bad URI(is not URI?): <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %> (URI::InvalidURIError) because of the database.yml I don't know why when I replace the embedded ruby code of the url with the real url the app works fine.

My database.yml:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  port: 5432
development:
  <<: *default
  database: <%= ENV['DATABASE_NAME'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['DATABASE_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
production:
  <<: *default
  url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
```

I use dotenv gem and I load the environment variables from another file out of my project directory.
Also, know that when I open the rails console on my ec2 machine I can connect to the database without any problem.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have find the answer in [another stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35786885/rails-database-yml-not-accepting-erb). Tproblem was that the database.yml was not accepting erb. So, I tried to do like the answer of the previous question and it worked fine